# Pyinstaller no suitable image found

Tags: macos, build, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I have PyInstaller version 4.0 installed on my system. I am attempting to build a python script using python 3.7.3. This python script imports other python scripts which have their own import statements.

I am building using the command:

pyinstaller --noconfirm --clean  script_to_build.py

However, when I run the new binary that is built, I get the following error:

When the file gets built, inside the dist folder there is a Foundation folder with two files, _Foundation.cpython-37m-darwin.so and _inlines.cpython-37m-darwin.so, and yet it's complaining about missing Foundation library. What does this error message mean and how do I fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 144, in __init__
  File "ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
OSError: dlopen(./dist/script_to_build/Foundation, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    ./dist/script_to_build/Foundation: not a file
    ./dist/script_to_build/Foundation: not a file

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_to_build.py", line 66, in <module>
    import script1
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "script1.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pyautogui/__init__.py", line 241, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "rubicon/objc/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "rubicon/objc/runtime.py", line 89, in <module>
  File "rubicon/objc/runtime.py", line 66, in load_library
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 146, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll './dist/script_to_build/Foundation'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Here's the updated command that works:

```
pyinstaller --add-binary "/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Resources/BridgeSupport/Foundation.dylib:." --onefile --noconfirm --clean script_to_build.py
```

I was able to compile the program with this, but when executing the binary I got the error "../../../../../../../../../Library/Python/3.7m/include/pyconfig.h could not be extracted!" In order to fix this error, I had to modify the function `relpath_to_config_or_make(filename)` file /Lirary/Python/3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/hooks/**init**.py as follows:

```
def relpath_to_config_or_make(filename):
    """
    The following is refactored out of hook-sysconfig and hook-distutils,
    both of which need to generate "datas" tuples for pyconfig.h and
    Makefile, under the same conditions.
    """

    # Relative path in the dist directory.
    prefix = _find_prefix(filename)
    rel_path = os.path.relpath(os.path.dirname(filename), prefix)
    if '../' in rel_path and is_darwin:
        new_path = os.path.relpath(os.path.abspath(rel_path), os.path.expanduser('~'))
    else:
        new_path = os.path.relpath(os.path.dirname(filename), prefix)
    return new_path
```

[Source for the 'could not be extracted' problem](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2367)